# Entity Framework Core Contains doesn't seem select the data I need

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

So I have this query that I had to use in our backend (.NET 6, Entity  Framework Core 7.0.5)

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM BulletinLinks BL 
     INNER JOIN Bulletins B ON BL.BulletinID = B.BulID
     WHERE (BL.MID = 'AUD30896') 
       AND (B.LangID = 4) 
       AND (B.Owner IN (1, 2)) 
       AND (B.ContentWords LIKE '%P2002%'))
    +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Bulletins AS B 
     WHERE (B.Status IN (9, 11, 13)) 
       AND (B.LangID = 4) 
       AND (B.Owner IN (1, 2)) 
       AND (B.ContentWords LIKE '%P2002%'))
```

Which I have rewritten to

```sql
var firstCountQuery = _db.BulletinLinks
    .Join(_db.Bulletins, bl => bl.BulletinID, bulletin => bulletin.BulID, (bulletinLink, bulletin) => new { bulletinLink, bulletin })
    .Where(b => b.bulletinLink.MID == modelId)
    .Where(b => b.bulletin.LangID == langId)
    .Where(b => new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(b.bulletin.Owner))
    .Where(b => b.bulletin.ContentWords.Contains(faultCode));

var secondCountQuery = _db.Bulletins
    .Where(bulletin => lookupStatusCodes.Contains(bulletin.Status))
    .Where(bulletin => bulletin.LangID == langId)
    .Where(bulletin => new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(bulletin.Owner))
    .Where(bulletin => bulletin.ContentWords.Contains(faultCode));
```

that I call `CountAsync` on later and sum them. But they give the wrong result, 3 instead of 5, but I can't exactly see what I'm missing.

There's something about the second query (I think), because if I compare the LINQ statements with the two other queries, I can see that `firstCountQuery` returns the expected results. And `secondCountQuery` only gives 1 instead of 3.

If I check the generated query

```
firstCountQuery.ToQueryString() + "\n\n" + secondCountQuery.ToQueryString()
```

then I get the following:

```sql
-- Formatted and with fields redacted

DECLARE @__modelId_0 CHAR ( 8 ) = 'AUD30896';
DECLARE
    @__langId_1 tinyint = CAST ( 4 AS tinyint );
DECLARE
    @__faultCode_2 nvarchar ( 4000 ) = N'P2002';
SELECT
  -- All properties
FROM
    [BulletinLinks] AS [b]
    INNER JOIN [Bulletins] AS [b0] ON [b].[BulletinID] = [b0].[BulID] 
WHERE
    [b].[MID] = @__modelId_0 
    AND [b0].[LangID] = @__langId_1 
    AND CAST ( [b0].[Owner] AS INT ) IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND ( ( @__faultCode_2 LIKE N'' ) OR CHARINDEX( @__faultCode_2, [b0].[ContentWords] ) > 0 );
    
    
DECLARE
    @__langId_2 tinyint = CAST ( 4 AS tinyint );
DECLARE
    @__faultCode_4 nvarchar ( 4000 ) = N'P2002';
SELECT
  -- All properties 
FROM
    [Bulletins] AS [b] 
WHERE
    CAST ( [b].[Status] AS INT ) IN ( 9, 11, 13 ) 
    AND [b].[LangID] = @__langId_2
    AND CAST ( [b].[Owner] AS INT ) IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND ( ( @__faultCode_4 LIKE N'' ) OR CHARINDEX( @__faultCode_4, [b].[ContentWords] ) > 0 )
```

And if I run those I get 2 results for the first, and 1 result for the second query. I think it has something to do with the last `AND` because if I replace it with `AND (B.ContentWords Like '%P2002%')` I get the 3 expected results.

So what am I missing?

Comment: First off you have too many where clauses and best to make it into one.  Example builtin.Where(x=>x.Id==id && x.LangID==langId) and regarding the contains you would do List<string> lookupstatuscodes = //list of status codes and then do lookupstatuscodes.Contains(x.Status).

Comment: @AliK Please elaborate

Comment: @AliK both versions ( multi "where" vs "&&" ) will translate to the exact same SQL.

Comment: @Fildor can confirm. https://gist.github.com/inabahare/963aa63ba4edb08d396195d2e4925160

Comment: what are the three `ContentWords` that match the `like` query but not `charindex`?

Comment: This is strange, like and charindex should be the same for a simple word thing

Comment: @Fildor I know.  I was just stating that one way is just better to read but that depends on individual choice I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just found the answer and it's called `EF.Functions.Like` and it's used like so:

```cs
var firstCountQuery = _db.BulletinLinks
    .Join(_db.Bulletins, bl => bl.BulletinID, bulletin => bulletin.BulID, (bulletinLink, bulletin) => new { bulletinLink, bulletin })
    .Where(b => b.bulletinLink.MID == modelId)
    .Where(b => b.bulletin.LangID == langId)
    .Where(b => new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(b.bulletin.Owner))
    .Where(b => EF.Functions.Like(b.bulletin.ContentWords, $"%{faultCodes}%"));

var secondCountQuery = _db.Bulletins
    .Where(bulletin => lookupStatusCodes.Contains(bulletin.Status))
    .Where(bulletin => bulletin.LangID == langId)
    .Where(bulletin => new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(bulletin.Owner))
    .Where(b => EF.Functions.Like(b.ContentWords, $"%{faultCodes}%"));
```

Which generates the following SQL

```sql
DECLARE @__langId_1 tinyint = CAST ( 4 AS tinyint );
DECLARE
    @__Format_3 nvarchar ( 4000 ) = N'%P2002%';
SELECT
    -- Redacted
FROM
    [Bulletins] AS [b] 
WHERE
    CAST ( [b].[Status] AS INT ) IN ( 9, 11, 13 ) 
    AND [b].[LangID] = @__langId_1 
    AND CAST ( [b].[Owner] AS INT ) IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND ( [b].[ContentWords] LIKE @__Format_3 )
```

And it seems to be just what I need. But I wonder why `Contains` doesn't do the job here?

Comment: And if I try to insert this ```"%' SELECT * FROM Bulletins WHERE Bulletins.BulID = 4004;--"``` it generates SQL without the '

Comment: You should probably try to get rid of that `CAST` also. What type is `LangID`, if it's a `long` then you should compare it with `long`s like `new[] { 1L, 2L }.Contains(bulletin.Owner)`